# Using javascript to change the background image over time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have been looking at how to do this on here, i have taken a few ideas and added them to my code but have no idea why its not working, i have tried everything (in my mind)!

I am looking for the headbar which is a div with a background image to change the the image over time!

**So here is my HTML**

```
<div id="headbar" onload="photoA()">

<div class="headbar-title">THE ALL NEW 14 RANGE</div>

<div class="button">FIND OUT MORE</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var imageCount = 1;
  var total = 6;
  window.setInterval(function photoA() {
  var headbar = document.getElementById('headbar');
  imageCount = imageCount + 1;
  if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}   
  headbar.style.backgroundImage = "url('..img/img"+ imageCount +".JPG') no-repeat center center";
  }
  ,1000);
</script>
```

"

**Here is my css**

```
#headbar {
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Any help will be massively appreciated! For now nothing is happening its just a white background!

(btw i haven't used much javascript,  used c only)

Thanks,

Ollie

Comment: The path for the image is invalid as you're missing a slash - `..img/img` should probably be `../img/img`

Comment: you should be using background and not backgroundImage i think...
backgroundImage doesnt have support for repeats

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you were both right! That fixed the issue! The only thing now is they are not following the "background-size: cover;" property and are massive! Any clue on how to solve that?

Comment: Also i how can i give you thumbs up for that? this was my first post so kinda clueless!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jQuery to do this instead of hard-coding your javascript. Something like this may work really well.

http://www.programming-free.com/2013/12/change-background-image-jquery.html